# How to replace specific rows (based on conditions) using values with similar features condition in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

i'm having a trouble when i wanna replace specific values that satisfies a condition and replace the values based on another condition.

#### Example of dataframe (df)

```
     Gender    Surname    Ticket
` 0   masc     Family1     a12`
` 1 **fem      NoGroup     aa3**`
` 2   boy      Family1     125`
` 3 **fem      Family2     aa3**`
` 4   fem      Family4     525`
` 5   masc     NoGroup     a52`
```

The condition to substitute de values in all rows of df['Surname'] column is:

`if ((df['Gender']!= masc) & (df['Surname'] == 'NoGroup'))`

The code must search for row that have equal ticket and substitute for the correspondent Surname value, else keep the value that already exists ('noGroup').

In this example, the ['Surname'] value in the row 1 ('noGroup') should be replace by 'family2', that corresponds row 3.

I tried this way, but it did not work

`for i in zip((df['Gender']!='man') & df['Surname']=='noGroup'):
    df['Surname'][i] = df.loc[df['Ticket']==df['Surname'][i]]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Pandas you should aim for vectorised calculations rather than row-wise loops. Here's one approach. First convert selected values to `None`:

```
df.loc[df['Gender'].ne('masc') & df['Surname'].eq('NoGroup'), 'Surname'] = None
```

Then create a series mapping from `Ticket` to `Surname` after a filter:

```
s = df[df['Surname'].notnull()].drop_duplicates('Ticket').set_index('Ticket')['Surname']
```

Finally, map null values with the calculated series:

```
df['Surname'] = df['Surname'].fillna(df['Ticket'].map(s))
```

Result:

```
  Gender  Surname Ticket
0   masc  Family1    a12
1    fem  Family2    aa3
2    boy  Family1    125
3    fem  Family2    aa3
4    fem  Family4    525
5   masc  NoGroup    a52
```